# Can I update my Nexus 7 from 4.2.2 to 4.3 and root it without losing data?

Tags: nexus-7, root-access, ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

Device: Nexus 7
Android: 4.2.2

Can I upgrade my Nexus 7 to 4.3 via OTA, then re-root without losing data? I used a procedure of this sort to root originally, but I don't know if it is generally possible.

Note: [I did not unlock the bootloader when I last rooted](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2233852).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO.

Updating from 4.2.2 to 4.3 will retain your data, but this will make you lose root. To root, you would need to unlock the bootloader, which will almost always require a Factory Reset (thus, you lose your data).

So, I suggest to back-up your user apps and data with Titanium Backup or something similar.

Comment: I didn't unlock the bootloader when I last rooted, so is that still true?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat How were you able to root before?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2233852

Comment: @JakobWeisblat I edited my answer